# camel escaping special characters from property file

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-camel

I've got a password in a property file

```
com.password=$&m
```

It is being inserted into an sftp camel route with `{{com.password}}` and I'm getting `"Unknown parameters=[{m=}]"`

& is being interpreted incorrectly. 
I've tried a few things, and can't find anything in the docs.  What do I do to make it use the password verbatim?

EDIT:

```
<cm:property-placeholder id="blueprint.placeholder" persistent-id="com.props" >
</cm:property-placeholder>
```

ROUTE:

```
<camel:route id="uploadqueue">  
    <camel:from uri="file://{{com.dir}}/?antInclude=*.xml&amp;delay=10000&amp;move=processed/${file:name}&amp;moveFailed=error/${file:name}" />
    <camel:to uri="log:input?showAll=true&amp;level=INFO"/>
    <camel:to uri="sftp://192.168.0.1/?username={{com.user}}&amp;password={{com.password}}" />
</camel:route>
```

EDIT: 
Route now:

```
 <camel:to uri="sftp://192.168.0.1/?username={{com.user}}&amp;password=RAW({{com.password}})" />
```

Stacktrace.  Slightly edited for confidentiality, but basically this. 
Password of $&m is interpreted as the HTML (%24) for $, as the password, & as the semantic ampersand, and m as a new parameter.  i.e. RAW() did nothing.

```
Caused by: org.apache.camel.ResolveEndpointFailedException: Failed to resolve endpoint: sftp://192.168.0.1/?password=%24&m=&username=USERNAME due to: There are 1 parameters that couldn't be set on the endpoint. Check the uri if the parameters are spelt correctly and that they are properties of the endpoint. Unknown parameters=[{m=}]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultComponent.validateParameters(DefaultComponent.java:215) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultComponent.createEndpoint(DefaultComponent.java:139) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.getEndpoint(DefaultCamelContext.java:711) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.camel.util.CamelContextHelper.getMandatoryEndpoint(CamelContextHelper.java:80) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.camel.model.RouteDefinition.resolveEndpoint(RouteDefinition.java:219) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultRouteContext.resolveEndpoint(DefaultRouteContext.java:115) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultRouteContext.resolveEndpoint(DefaultRouteContext.java:121) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.camel.model.SendDefinition.resolveEndpoint(SendDefinition.java:62) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.camel.model.SendDefinition.createProcessor(SendDefinition.java:56) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.camel.model.ProcessorDefinition.makeProcessorImpl(ProcessorDefinition.java:562) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.camel.model.ProcessorDefinition.makeProcessor(ProcessorDefinition.java:523) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.camel.model.ProcessorDefinition.addRoutes(ProcessorDefinition.java:239) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.camel.model.RouteDefinition.addRoutes(RouteDefinition.java:1300) ~[?:?]
    ... 26 more
```

Comment: Could you please add your route definition as well? 
Remember to remove sensitive information like credentials, IP Addresses etc.

Comment: Added minimal route example

Comment: try this `<camel:to uri="sftp://192.168.0.1/?username={{com.user}}&amp;password=RAW({{com.password}})"`

Comment: Checkout [this part](https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/faq/how-do-i-configure-endpoints.html#HowdoIconfigureendpoints-Usingpropertyplaceholders) of the docs and use `RAW()`. If that doesn't work, please post the stacktrace too.

Comment: I see it in the stacktrace! How about changing config file to `com.password=RAW($&m)` and revert change on the route?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/faq/how-do-i-configure-password-options-on-camel-endpoints-without-the-value-being-encoded.html) this should work.

```
<camel:to uri="sftp://192.168.0.1/?username={{com.user}}&amp;password=RAW({{com.password}})"
```

Comment: Could you please post the stack trace?

Comment: sorry, lemme check something, I think it might work actually.  Got something else wrong

Comment: Ok, my bad.  It did work.  I just had the password twice, because the actual route had a redeliveryPolicy bit with the password again.